# javax.xml library adds ^M characters while writing to file

Tags: java, xml

I have this following code to write a string to xml file:

```
private void writeToCucumberXml(Document doc, String filePath) throws TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
```

doc is document that is created by parsing an xml file.

The generated output (after running in the windows environment) when opened in the vi (cygwin environment) shows a lot of ^M characters. How can I make the xml file writer skip writing the ^M characters?

Comment: `^M` is the CR part of the Windows line ending (CRLF) where Unix only uses LF. It's harmless, any XML parser will just ignore it. If you want to remove it, look for unix tools like dos2unix or switch the line ending mode in vi.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want xml writer to add these extra characters. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you writing the file on Windows? It probably uses the platform default, and if you write on Windows you'll get CRLF. You can try to pass an `OutputStream` to the `StreamResult` constructor and have that stream convert from DOS to Unix line endings.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for your response. I created an outputstream StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath))); but not sure how I can handle the logic for EOL conversion.  I don't see any method in the output stream to instruct how to handle the EOL. Do you mean to say to create an anonymous class with overridden method to handle the EOL processing logic?